Python PyPDF2 dont generate correctly PDF
I'm generating a PDF using another PDF as a format, which is okay. However, when I try to send it via SMTP, the attachment is not visible in the email. It's only correctly visible via Firefox/Chrome, not via Adobe or email viewers (This only shows blank document). My code is simple: I read a CSV and generate a PDF using another PDF as a format. I tried converting it to images and then to PDF, but nothing works. I also tried changing encoding, font, etc., but still no luck. I've spent many hours on this issue. If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it. Here's the code; I will skip SMTP because the code for it is correct.
Code:
import csv
import io
from datetime import datetime
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from config import name_column, address_column, email_column  # Import specific variables from config
from smtp import sendmail  # Import the sendmail function from smtp module
import random

def extraer_codigo_ciudad(direccion):
    partes = direccion.split(", ")
    codigo_postal = partes[-3]
    ciudad = partes[-2]
    return codigo_postal, ciudad

def extraer_direccion(direccion):
    partes = direccion.split(", ")
    direccion_sin_cp_ciudad = ", ".join(partes[:-2])
    return direccion_sin_cp_ciudad

ID = ''.join(random.choices('0123456789', k=9))
IBAN = 'ES1234567891012131415161'

def generate_pdf(file_name, name, address, format_pdf, email):
    reader = PdfReader(open(format_pdf, 'rb'))
    writer = PdfWriter()

    for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
        page = reader.pages[page_num]
        writer.add_page(page)

    packet = io.BytesIO()
    can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
    can.setFont("Helvetica", 10)

    can.drawString(95, 360, f" {name}")
    can.setFont("Helvetica", 9)
    can.drawString(100, 700, f" {ID}")
    can.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 8)
    can.drawString(295, 568.5, f" {IBAN}")

    can.save()

    packet.seek(0)
    new_pdf = PdfReader(packet)

    page = writer.get_page(1)
    page.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0])

    packet = io.BytesIO()
    can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
    can.setFont("Helvetica", 10)

    codigo_postal, ciudad = extraer_codigo_ciudad(address)
    can.drawString(330, 650, name)
    can.drawString(330, 630, extraer_direccion(address))
    can.drawString(330, 610, codigo_postal + " " + ciudad)
    
    execution_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    can.drawString(90, 535, f" {execution_date}")
    
    can.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 10)
    can.drawString(235, 514, name)
    can.drawString(186, 500, ID)
    
    can.save()

    packet.seek(0)
    new_pdf = PdfReader(packet)

    page = writer.get_page(0)
    page.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0])

    with open(f"{file_name}.pdf", 'wb') as output_pdf:
        writer.write(output_pdf)
        #print(str(output_pdf) + ' sent to ' + str(output_pdf))
    
    sendmail(f"{file_name}.pdf", email)

def process_csv(filename, format_pdf):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(reader)  # Skip header row
        for row in reader:
            file_name = "Invoice_" + str(random.randint(1, 100000))
            full_name = row[name_column].strip()  # Use the column index to extract the name
            address = row[address_column].strip()  # Use the column index to extract the address
            email = row[email_column].strip()  # Use the column index to extract the email
            generate_pdf(file_name, full_name, address, format_pdf, email)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_csv("data_csv.csv", "format.pdf")


